# Context Broker crashing with certain update queries

Tags: mongodb, fiware-orion

We're running the Context Broker on a CentOS server but it keeps crashing with certain update queries. We've tried version 0.26 and the latest 1.0.0-1 but the result is the same, we've also tried changing the mongoDB version between 3.0.6 and 3.0.7 but no luck. The logs doesn't give us much to go on so that's why we're asking here in SO.

What we're doing is to send an update of an entity of about 1MB in size routed in from a http call via nginx. The context broker crashes (see logs below) but mongodb and other services continue to function normally.

Log file: /var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.log

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'mongo::MsgAssertionException'
  what():  EOO Before end of object
```

Log file: /var/log/messages

```
Apr 28 07:15:50 gl abrt[11457]: Saved core dump of pid 11426 (/usr/bin/contextBroker) to /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-04-28-07:15:49-11426 (63606784 bytes)
Apr 28 07:15:50 gl abrtd: Directory 'ccpp-2016-04-28-07:15:49-11426' creation detected
Apr 28 07:15:50 gl abrtd: Package 'contextBroker' isn't signed with proper key
Apr 28 07:15:50 gl abrtd: 'post-create' on '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-04-28-07:15:49-11426' exited with 1
Apr 28 07:15:50 gl abrtd: Deleting problem directory '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-04-28-07:15:49-11426'
```

Output from the contextBroker when it's run in verbose mode:

```
INFO@14:05:27  logMsg.h[1792]: Starting transaction from 127.0.0.1:51245/v1/updateContext
INFO@14:05:27  connectionOperations.cpp[78]: Database Operation Successful (query: { id.id: "8a55c32500dfad.....06be56709b75b31c1f9beb7d2", id.type: "House", _id.servicePath: /^\/$/ })
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'mongo::MsgAssertionException'
  what():  BSONElement: bad type 100
```

Any ideas about what could be causing this, or where we should continue looking?

Comment: It would be great if we could have a look to the updateContext request payload you are using. Could you provide a link to it, please? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for responding! We've done some more testing this morning and see that the actual request isn't that large and doesn't seem to be the problem. We're able to make it crash now manually by just sending in a simple command via curl/cli that deletes an attribute. The total data in the entity is about 1.1MB (eg larger than the payload limit) could that be the problem, even though the payload isn't over the limit? Could I maybe send you the entity data (as xml, or a dump from mongodb) in a PM so that you can try it locally?

Comment: Yes, please, send me a mongo dumpo of the entity to make a local test. In addition, it would be great if you could edit your question post to include the command via curl/cli that deletes the attribute. Thanks!

Comment: @fgalan Ok great! I'd rather not post a link to the db-dump here since it contains production data, how can I reach you in a PM? Could you maybe send me your email address by posting something in our [support form](http://www.groplay.com/app-support/) (which will send me an email that I can use to reply with a link to the db dump)

Answer (score 0):

This crash is due to [a bug](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2112) detected at Orion. A fix is [on the way](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/pull/2113), so we hope it get merged and ready to be included in next Orion release (Orion 1.2.0).